# 500 (Internal Server Error) - jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 - xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I use the following JQuery function to send an ajax request.

```
// On submit, we send an ajax request instead.
    $('body').on('submit', '.ajaxForm', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.rangeField').trigger('prePost');
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('form').find('button').prop('disabled',false);
            $('#waitingGif').hide();
            viewManager.setView('results', {data: dataPreparator.apply(data)});
        })
    });
```

But i get everytime an error from the JQuery Lib (from here):

```
            try {

                // Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
                xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
            } catch ( e ) {

                // #14683: Only rethrow if this hasn't been notified as an error yet
                if ( callback ) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        },
```

and from the server like:

```
POST http://localhost/redesign/neonetweb/symfony/web/data/eval/menu/custom/menu?…5Bsex%5D=2&app_custom_eval%5Bweight%5D=850&app_custom_eval%5Byears%5D=2012 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

with the following details:

```
send    @   jquery-3.3.1.js:9600
ajax    @   jquery-3.3.1.js:9206
(anonymous) @   menu?app_custom_eval…val[years]=2012:523
dispatch    @   jquery-3.3.1.js:5183
elemData.handle @   jquery-3.3.1.js:4991
```

I really don't know what could be the reason for this error at times ...it worked 2 months ago. I tried to use diffrent version from JQuery but it didn't helped me. As well i wrote this function under JQuery 2.2.1 like this, hoping to learn more about the mistake... i got as well a mistake from the JQuery Lib.

```
$('body').on('submit', '.ajaxForm', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.rangeField').trigger('prePost');
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('form').find('button').prop('disabled',false);
            $('#waitingGif').hide();
            viewManager.setView('results', {data: dataPreparator.apply(data)});
        }).error(function(err) {
            console.log('ERROR!');
            console.log(err);
            alert('Server returned with error message: ' + err.responseText);
            $('form').find('button').prop('disabled',false);
            $('#waitingGif').hide();
        });
    });
```

Now i hope somebody can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: A `500 Internal Server Error` is an error that occurs on the server side - not in your client side javascript code. You should inspect your server logs to see what the actual error was.

Comment: You're seeing the error in the context of jquery because the ajax request is returning an error and jquery is letting you know that the request failed. In this case, jquery is working as expected - the issue seems to be in the server.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your Feedback!...I found the mistake  in the middle of my logfiles.

Comment: Happy to help, @helmi! Was the issue related at all to your client side javascript? Or was it only a server side issue?

Comment: It was a server side issue in a SQL statement... I was a little bit surprised because i didnt get a stacktrace from symfony just this exception in the JQuery lib.